# How does the Sequelize POJO JSON.stringify magic work?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In sequelize if you do a

```
db.MyTable.findAll({}).function(response){
    console.log(response);
}
```

You will see output that looks like this (depending on what your table looks like, of course):

```
[ { dataValues:
     { id: 1,
       text: 'sdf',
       complete: false,
       createdAt: Thu Jan 19 2017 11:55:38 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
       updatedAt: Thu Jan 19 2017 11:55:38 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) },
    _previousDataValues:
     { id: 1,
       text: 'sdf',
       complete: false,
       createdAt: Thu Jan 19 2017 11:55:38 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
       updatedAt: Thu Jan 19 2017 11:55:38 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) },
    _changed: {},
    '$modelOptions':
     { timestamps: true,
       instanceMethods: {},
       classMethods: {},
       validate: {},
       freezeTableName: false,
       underscored: false,
       underscoredAll: false,
       paranoid: false,
       rejectOnEmpty: false,
       whereCollection: null,
       schema: null,
       schemaDelimiter: '',
       defaultScope: {},
       scopes: [],
       hooks: {},
       indexes: [],
       name: [Object],
       omitNul: false,
       sequelize: [Object],
       uniqueKeys: {},
       hasPrimaryKeys: true },
    '$options':
     { isNewRecord: false,
       '$schema': null,
       '$schemaDelimiter': '',
       raw: true,
       attributes: [Object] },
    hasPrimaryKeys: true,
    __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
    isNewRecord: false } ]
```

Suffice to say, it is a big complex object with a bunch of metaData on it.

However, if you try and turn that big complicated object into a string using either:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(dbTodo));
```

or

```
res.json(dbTodo);
```

you will get back just the information for the actual entity (the items in the dataValues property of the big complex object). For my test table here, it looks like this:

```
[{
    "id":1,
    "text":"sdf",
    "complete":false,
    "createdAt":"2017-01-19T16:55:38.000Z",
    "updatedAt":"2017-01-19T16:55:38.000Z"
 }]
```

Which is significantly simpler (and just what I want).

How does this magic happen? Is sequelize creating their own versions of JSON.stringify() and express' res.json?

What are the rules around when it happens and when it doesn't happen?

I've searched through the [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/instances/) [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/instance/) and haven't found a good explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways this behavior could manifest.

1. The missing properties are non-enumerable. Properties defined by [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) set to `enumerable: false` (or simply don't supply a value for the `enumerable` setting) are non-enumerable properties, and are ignored by `JSON.stringify`. You can check a property's `enumerable` setting in the output of [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, propName)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor).
2. The object has (or has in its prototype chain) a [`toJSON` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior):

   > If an object being stringified has a property named `toJSON` whose value is a function, then the `toJSON()` method customizes JSON stringification behavior: instead of the object being serialized, the value returned by the `toJSON()` method when called will be serialized.

   If the object has or inherits a `toJSON` method, then the return value of that method will be the target for stringification. You can check if one exists on some object `obj` simply by reading the value of `obj.toJSON`.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks.