# right way using async , double then() in promise? node8, need really babel to es5?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise, babeljs

UPDATED:

*the question about console stringify is duplicated; so i've changed my question to another with async, because is the sam ecode*

I have an async function, that get a record throug sequelize orm, why

My question is

```
const genericResolver = async ( table, action , values ) => {

    resultValues = {};
    let resultValues =   await models[table].findById(values.id).then( function (data) {
      console.log(' ************** data');
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    }).then( function (data2) {
       console.log(' ************** data 2');
       console.log(data2);
      }
    );
    console.log('------ resultValues');
    console.log(resultValues );
    process.exit(1);

for data and data2 I get:

    tour {
      dataValues: 
       { id: 'd61802ff-3eec-4a72-97ca-832f51b96bf0',
         name: 'Chipre 2018',
         price: '1400.00',
         createdAt: 2017-09-05T04:01:27.642Z,
         updatedAt: 2017-10-31T11:29:39.484Z },
      _previousDataValues: 
       { id: 'd61802ff-3eec-4a72-97ca-832f51b96bf0',
         name: 'Chipre 2018',
         price: '1400.00',
         createdAt: 2017-09-05T04:01:27.642Z,
         updatedAt: 2017-10-31T11:29:39.484Z },
      _changed: {},
      _modelOptions: 
       { timestamps: true,
         validate: {},
         freezeTableName: true,
         underscored: false,
         underscoredAll: false,
         paranoid: false,
         rejectOnEmpty: false,
         whereCollection: { id: 'd61802ff-3eec-4a72-97ca-832f51b96bf0' },
         schema: null,
         schemaDelimiter: '',
         defaultScope: {},
         scopes: [],
         hooks: {},
         indexes: [],
         name: { plural: 'tour', singular: 'tour' },
         omitNull: false,
         sequelize: 
          Sequelize {
            options: [Object],
            config: [Object],
            dialect: [Object],
            queryInterface: [Object],
            models: [Object],
            modelManager: [Object],
            connectionManager: [Object],
            importCache: {},
            test: [Object] },
         uniqueKeys: {} },
      _options: 
       { isNewRecord: false,
         _schema: null,
         _schemaDelimiter: '',
         raw: true,
         attributes: 
          [ 'id',
            'name',
            'price',
            'seatsmax',
            'createdAt',
            'updatedAt' ] },
      __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
      isNewRecord: false }
```

but for 'resultValues' I get:

```
undefined
```

I'm doing right with async? i'm using node8 so in theory i don't need babel convert everything to ES5 ? just import or export? I suspect that babel is creating ES6 code

Here my package.json

```
{
  "name": "myproj",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "GraphQL server",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./server.js --exec babel-node -e js",
    "test": "eslint . --ext .js --ext .jsx --ignore-path .gitignore --cache"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.22.0",
    "eslint": "^4.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.3",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "graphql": "^0.9.1",
    "graphql-server-express": "^0.6.0",
    "graphql-tools": "^0.10.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^3.0.0",
    "pg": "^7.2.0",
    "sequelize": "",
    "validator": "^6.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Sequelize POJO JSON.stringify magic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41747844/how-does-the-sequelize-pojo-json-stringify-magic-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because objects are passed as reference in JS, so when you do `console.log(o)`, you will see the actual value in console (not the value you passed to it when calling `console.log`).

When you use `JSON.stringify`, you are logging string, which is passed by value. So basically when you use JSON, you will see the value by the time of calling `console.log`.

**EDIT**

As to your new question, problem is that you do not return `data2` from the second `then` callback. When using `async/await`, you do not need to use `then` at all:

```
const data = await models[table].findById(values.id);
```

Or if you want, just return `data2` and you should see the same result in `resultValues`:

```
let resultValues = await models[table].findById(values.id).then(data => {
    console.log(' ************** data');
    console.log(data);
    return data;
}).then(data2 => {
    console.log(' ************** data 2');
    console.log(data2);

    return data2; // <== return here
});

console.log('------ resultValues');
console.log(resultValues );
```

Comment: the real is console.log(o) then? there is a way to get same value with a technique ?

Comment: what  I dont' understand from where come the value in stringfy? i've not changed that value i think

Comment: No, the actual value is preserved only when using JSON. problem is not with `console.log`, but with your code - you are expecting to have some properties there, at the time when there are not yet assigned. You are probably assigning them later (this can happen in different place than the file you are using).

Comment: sorry thahks, but my question was marked like duplicated so i was advised to change the question

Comment: I see. The problem with `resultValues` being `undefined` is that you do not return `data` from your second `then` callback.

Comment: thanks what babel need for node8?, has support for native, i suspect my babel is compiling to es5

Comment: If you will run the code on node 8, you do not need babel at all I think as `async/await` is supported already.